# In_array doesn't see element in DateTimeZone::ALL_WITH_BC, why?

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

Sorry for my english (Google translator helps)))

The general task is to check the presence of a time zone in the received cookie. If "Found", send it to the variable, if not "Not Found", the default variable.

I display a list of DateTimeZone::ALL_WITH_BC timezones, when the list changes, a cookie with value is created, by in_array, a check in the DateTimeZone::ALL_WITH_BC array. But values with a plus sign + do not pass the check, i.e. Etc/GMT+3, etc.

Sample code:

```
<?php
echo '<select id="List">';
$tzlist = DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(DateTimeZone::ALL_WITH_BC);
foreach($tzlist as $value)
{
echo '<option value='. $value .'>'. $value .'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
$takeCookie = $_COOKIE['cookie'];
if (in_array($takeCookie, DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(DateTimeZone::ALL_WITH_BC))) 
{
echo "Found";
} 
else {
echo "Not Found";
}
?>
```

```
<script>
  $("#List").change(function() {
  var tz = $(this).val();
  document.cookie = "cookie="+tz;
    });
</script>
```

When choosing the time zone and refreshing the page, all values are "Found", except for those with +, why?

For example, select from the list:

```
<option value="Etc/GMT+9">Etc/GMT+9</option>
```

Cookie type:

```
cookie=Etc/GMT+9
```

Example code above shows "Not Found".

**UPD**
Ok, the problem is not In_array))

The problem is here:

```
<script>
    document.cookie = "cookie=Etc/GMT+9";
</script>

<?php
var_dump($_COOKIE['cookie']);
?>
```

Result:

```
string(9) "Etc/GMT 9"
```

Where is the plus (+) sign?

Comment: Note you aren't closing `</select>` correctly. Beyond that, what is the specific error thrown?

Comment: You probably want to use `encodeURIComponent` on the cookie value, as the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) suggests.

Comment: @charlietfl, You are correct about `</select>`, but this does not solve the problem of checking a value with a + sign.

Comment: Again...what is the specific error?

Comment: @charlietfl, Probably wrote incorrectly. It's not about "Error", it's just a message. `echo "Error"`.

Comment: Well do some basic debugging ... dump the array and dump the `$takeCookie` and see if they are as expected

Comment: @charlietfl, I corrected the question.

Comment: @charlietfl, like this? `var_dump($takeCookie);`
`var_dump(in_array($takeCookie, DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(DateTimeZone::ALL_WITH_BC))) ;` result: `string(9) "Etc/GMT 9" bool(false)`. + sign disappears.

Comment: Why is + missing?

Comment: @Jeto, you're right.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you  @Jeto, helped using encodeURIComponent. Like:

```
<script>
     document.cookie = "cookie="+encodeURIComponent('Etc/GMT+9');
</script>
```